# How to select value from drop down using webdriverjs (not selenium-webdriverjs)

Tags: webdriver, cucumberjs, webdriver-io

How to select/click value using webdrivejs API.
I don't find any direct API for selecting value from drop-down, can some one help me in this.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="appointment_provider_id" name="appointment[provider_id]" class="valid">

<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="9" selected="selected">Garr Ty</option>
<option value="12">lydia</option>
<option value="15">Black Keith</option>
<option value="13">tanmay.bagchi@people10.com</option>
<option value="17">Dr Nair S Ajesh</option>
<option value="3">Benjamin</option>
<option value="5"></option>

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs/issues/161

```
.click('//*[@id="id"]/option[3]')
    .getValue('#select',function(err,val){
        console.log(val); // will output value of "3"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question tag above contains Webdriver-io I hope below will be helpful to someone.

There are two ways you can do this:

1) using an attribute --> [link to Webdriver-io docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/selectByAttribute.html)

2) using index --> [link to Webdriver-io docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/selectByIndex.html)

.

1) using an attribute - Code extracted from source (link above):

```js
it('Should demonstrate the selectByAttribute command', () => {
    const selectBox = $('#selectbox');
    const value = selectBox.getValue();
    console.log(value); // returns "someValue0"

    selectBox.selectByAttribute('value', 'someValue3');
    console.log(selectBox.getValue()); // returns "someValue3"

    selectBox.selectByAttribute('name', 'someName5');
    console.log(selectBox.getValue()); // returns "someValue5"
});
```

```html
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="someValue0">uno</option>
    <option value="someValue1">dos</option>
    <option value="someValue2">tres</option>
    <option value="someValue3">cuatro</option>
    <option value="someValue4">cinco</option>
    <option name="someName5" value="someValue5">seis</option>
</select>
```

2) using index - Code extracted from source (link above):

```js
it('Should demonstrate the selectByIndex command', () => {
    const selectBox = $('#selectbox');
    console.log(selectBox.getValue()); // returns "someValue0"
    selectBox.selectByIndex(4);
    console.log(selectBox.getValue()); // returns "someValue4"
});
```

```html
<select id="selectbox">
    <option value="someValue0">uno</option>
    <option value="someValue1">dos</option>
    <option value="someValue2">tres</option>
    <option value="someValue3">cuatro</option>
    <option value="someValue4">cinco</option>
    <option value="someValue5">seis</option>
</select>
```